# @animate changes the scope of variables

Tags: variables, scope, julia

I am struggling with a weird error. I'm new to Julia so maybe I don't understand something.

Consider the code:

```
using Plots;
xyz = 1
anim = @animate for (j, iterated_variable) in enumerate(1:10)
    xyz = xyz
    plot(1,1)
end
```

it will yield the error "UndefVarError: xyz not defined"

while

```
xyz = 1
anim = @animate for (j, iterated_variable) in enumerate(1:10)
    print(xyz)
    plot(1,1)
end
```

will run and (oddly enough) print exactly:

`11`1111

`1111`

where the digits 1,2,7,8,9,10 are printed in monospace and the others in the regular font.

Removing the @animation handle makes the code do what you expect it to do.

```
xyz = 1
for (j, iterated_variable) in enumerate(1:10)
    print(xyz)
    plot(1,1)
end
```

and it will output

`1111111111`.

This error is quite frustrating I must admit, especially since I really am starting to like Julia. Any idea of what is happening?

Julia 1.6.3, VSCodium 1.66.1, Julia language support v1.6.17, notebooks

(edited the question, there was a code mistake)

Comment: I was able to understand it. Apparently adding an @ animate will "wrap" the function and thus change the scope of variables.

Answer (score 0):

If by notebooks you mean Pluto.jl notebooks and you run the first snippet all in one cell moving `using Plots` in a different one should fix the issue